# Operations on multiple Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data frames are provided:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'B':[2, 3]})
C = pd.DataFrame({'C':[4, 5]})
```

and list `d = [A, C, B, B]`

How to write an mathematical operations `(((A + C) * B) - B)` on frame values to create a new data frame?

The result is, for example, a frame in the form:

```
e = pd.DataFrame({'E':[8, 18]})
```

Comment: You could also just do `(a.A + C.C) * b.B - b.B` quite simply.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Massacre:D Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. I still like Max's solution better, because it offers you much more flexibility.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ And I'm still trying with the previous problem. I think he can do just that. Theoretically, I have only one function, let's assume that the solution to my problem would be to create a loop with the function `((A * B) * C) * A)` and so on. Because in that solution the code gives separate solutions for each element, comparing them still to the first one  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [132]: formula = "E = (((A + C) * B) - B)"

In [133]: pd.concat([a,b,C], axis=1).eval(formula, inplace=False)
Out[133]:
   A  B  C   E
0  1  2  4   8
1  2  3  5  18

In [134]: pd.concat([a,b,C], axis=1).eval(formula, inplace=False)[['E']]
Out[134]:
    E
0   8
1  18
```